# CopyCopter with ActiveAdmin gets loads of Timeout Errors.

Tags: activeadmin, copycopter

I am using CopyCopter with ActiveAdmin.  I get the following Timeout Errors in the messages and the Admin side moves like molasses.  Why is copycopter even being messaged from the ActiveAdmin views?  What part of the handshake am I missing?

```
14 matches for "Copycopter" in buffer: *run*
     12:** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108530607720] Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error
     16:** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] Downloaded translations
     22:** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error
     38:** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] Timeout::Error: execution expired
     43:** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error
     55:** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] Downloaded translations
     60:** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error
     72:** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] Downloaded translations
     79:** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] Timeout::Error: execution expired
    191:** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] No new translations
    196:** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error
    204:** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] Timeout::Error: execution expired
    244:** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] Downloaded translations
    249:** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error
```

A little more context for some messages above:

```
Started GET "/assets/active_admin/nested_menu_arrow_dark.gif" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:36:34 -0400
Served asset /active_admin/nested_menu_arrow_dark.gif - 200 OK (7ms)


Started GET "/admin/my_page" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:36:50 -0400
** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] Timeout::Error: execution expired
Processing by Admin::MyPageController#index as HTML
  AdminUser Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered /Users/cmmagid/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails32/gems/activeadmin-0.4.4/app/views/active_admin/page/index.html.arb (40.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 48ms (Views: 43.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
** [Copycopter] [P:12387] [T:70108512996560] Timeout::Error: Timeout::Error


Started GET "/assets/active_admin.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-31 10:37:01 -0400
Served asset /active_admin.css - 304 Not Modified (4ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Copycopter should not be messaged from the views. The client works by forking a process and contacting Copycopter every 300 seconds. That number is configurable in the `polling_delay` setting:

https://github.com/copycopter/copycopter-ruby-client/blob/master/lib/copycopter_client/configuration.rb

Maybe the logs above look like Copycopter is part of the app's GET requests because Copycopter's output is being mixed into the logs at funny times.

The `Timeout::Error` I assume is a problem on the `copycopter-server` side. How is the server being run? Is it on Heroku with one dyno and the app is going to sleep after 20 or 30 seconds of inactivity? That would be my guess since it is occasionally downloading the translations according to the logs:

`Downloaded translations 249`